# In ∆ ABC, the altitude AD and the median BM are equal in length and they intersect inside ∆ ABC. If ABC is not an equilateral triangle, ∠MBC is

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

I have got no clue on how to proceed with the question as nothing is given except Median of one side =altitude of another moreover they also removed the possibility of equilateral triangle.

Comment: Is this an ongoing competition as well?

Comment: Dear Ayush, such easy questions are atmost PreRMO level. Please don't use INMO name in title. It is confusing for other users. Have you seen past INMO question papers? They are available on web.

Comment: Sorry @cosmo5 I had actually a course on IOQM-INMO and this question was in that, will take great care from now on before posting such questions. Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Area can found by: $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$ ; where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$

$$\text{Area of $\Delta$ABC}=\text{$2\times$ Area of $\Delta$MBC}$$
$$\require{cancel}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\bcancel{\text{AD}}\cdot\text{BC}=2\times\frac{1}{2}\cdot\bcancel{\text{BM}}\cdot\text{BC}\cdot(\sin\angle\text{MBC})\tag{$\because$ AD=BM}$$
$$\fbox{$\therefore\angle\text{MBC}=30^o$}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $MK$ be an altitude of $\Delta MBC$.

Thus, $$MK=\frac{1}{2}BM,$$ which says $$\measuredangle MBC=30^{\circ}.$$

Comment: INMO questions are so difficult?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju it is PRMO level as mentioned above, my bad sorry :(